# Pulling props up before component in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a logging component where I set a form name - this is a string value set before the main component

This has been fine but now have a component used multiple times on a page and I need to give it a unique form name - however as this is set before the component I can't give it any prop values or states, here's the code;

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Logger, {LOG_LEVELS, ALL_MESSAGES} from '../../utils/logger'

const FORM_NAME = 'COMPANY_FORM'
const log = new Logger(FORM_NAME, LOG_LEVELS.DEBUG);

export class CompanyForm extends Component {

    render() {
        const uniqueCompayName = this.props.FORM_NAME_FOR_COMPANY
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is something like this but I'm not sure if it's possible

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Logger, {LOG_LEVELS, ALL_MESSAGES} from '../../utils/logger'

const FORM_NAME = 'COMPANY_FORM' + CompanyForm(this.props.uniqueCompayName)
const log = new Logger(FORM_NAME, LOG_LEVELS.DEBUG);

export class CompanyForm extends Component {

    render() {
        const uniqueCompayName = this.props.FORM_NAME_FOR_COMPANY
    }
}
```

Hope that's clear!

Comment: Why not set those values within the CompanyForm class component?

Answer (score 0):

you can move your naming logic to constructor, so that whenever you render your component you'll get the name set before you render the component.

The code below will work for you

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Logger, {LOG_LEVELS, ALL_MESSAGES} from '../../utils/logger'

export class CompanyForm extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.FORM_NAME = 'COMPANY_FORM' + CompanyForm(props.uniqueCompayName)
this.log = new Logger(FORM_NAME, LOG_LEVELS.DEBUG);
    }
    render() {
        const uniqueCompayName = this.FORM_NAME_FOR_COMPANY
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! @Sumit This is exactly what I thought would make sense but I can't make it work - as soon as I move any of this to constructor all I see is messages stating that 'log' is not defined

Comment: updated it. Now you've to refrence log as this.log in this component.

Comment: Ohh Ok I get the idea @Sumit - I still have the same problem saying log is not defined but I'll see if I can tweak it to work

Comment: make sure you're calling this.log in right context.